# absolute positioned images moving around

Tags: css

I have three images on my site which are absolute positioned. When I zoom in or out, the images move up and down. Is there any way around this? Because the issue involved so many elements i thought it was best to link to the site rather than type the entire CSS?

The images in question are the white clouds, blue clouds and the hills.

[www.beulahprint.ie/energy.html](http://www.beulahprint.ie/energy.html)

Cheers,
Colm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the "hills" into the footer-div, give the footer a "position:relative" and position the "hills" with "position:absolute"

Comment: Thanks a mil mate, that works a treat. I've done the same with the blue clouds at the bottom. I might leave the clouds fixed so they scroll with the page, it kinda makes things looks more real-life? Opinions?

Comment: The white line is there because .gif doesn't support transparency-levels...a pixel is either fully transparent or not transparent at all. A better choice would be a .png - there you can "fade out" the green pixels to smoothly integrate the image with the backgroud.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it up, I changed "matte" from black to the colour of the grass. But the image is slightly rough around the edges. When I use ng-24, there is some colour loss, the hills don't match the grass colour. Is there a way around this with pngs?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `fixed` instead of absolute.

Comment: fixed is the same but also when I scroll down the page....the images scroll with me.

Comment: @Moppy Is your objective that the images stay in exactly the same spot when you zoom in or out??

Comment: no sorry, I misunderstood your question. i want the hills to stay at exactly the same position on the grass. So the grass footer will stick to the bottom of the screen and the hills will stay at the same place on the grass. The blue clouds should be sitting right on top of the grass too when I zoom in or out

Comment: @Moppy - absolute generates an absolutely positioned element, positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. fixed generates an absolutely positioned element, positioned relative to the browser window. It seems that you want to position these items relative to others.

Comment: yeah I guess so? But which element do I position the images relative to?

Or maybe i'm doing this whole thing wrong? Is having 4 background images a bit cumbersome? Is there a better way to construct this background?